# What does 「行く」mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

From Persona 5:

> 近々、財団主催の美術展が開催される。 君の学校にもじき、公募の通知が行くだろう。

What does 「行く」mean in this sentence? I interpreted the second sentence as "A notification will soon be sent to your school about the event," but I've never seen 行く used like this before.

Comment: You can think it's 'to arrive'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just "go". This is a completely normal use of 行く, and there is nothing unnatural about it. The sentence means "A call for submissions will **go** to your school shortly".

Well, in English, "will be sent" might be more natural than "will go" in this context, whereas in Japanese, 行く is more common than 送られる. But we already know many examples like this (e.g., "I like cats" is more common than "I am fond of cats" in English, but 猫が好きだ is more common than 猫を好む in Japanese). Understanding the basic meaning of 行く here shouldn't be tricky.